# "For y in range(1,x)" loops taking too long to run. How can one expedite this process in Python?

Tags: python

This code takes 40 seconds to run with an order of 1000. I need to run it while order = 100,000,000. Is there a way for me to speed up this code?

```
from fractions import Fraction

x=5
order=1000
count=0
while x <=order:
    for y in range(1,x):
        if str(Fraction(y/x).limit_denominator()) != "%s/%s"%(y,x):
            print(Fraction(y/x).limit_denominator())
            count += 1
    print(" ")
    x+=1

count= (count + 1) * 6 + (order -1)*6
print(count)
```

The purpose of this code was to decipher problem #351 on Project Euler. I have a limited understanding of Python, so I tried to use what I know to figure it out. I initially figured each line of hidden green dots was an easy find (`(n-1)* 6`), but determining the center dots was a greater challenge. Finding out that the pattern of each obstructed green dots was not linear, but rather a matter of considering the rows of each of the six present triangles as fractions, and finding the fractions that simplify. This code parses each "row" of the triangle for fractions that are simplified. If it finds one the code adds 1 to the variable 'count'. Since the while loop starts at row 5, (1 row beyond the first green dot) I had to add those dots back to the final count at the end (`(count + 1)* 6`). I used this code to confirm the green dots found in the order of 1000. It took 40 seconds to run though. 100,000,000 will likely take a bit longer (upwards of a few days to a few weeks.) I've been running it on a computer for over a day and a half as of January 11th, 2018 11:34pm EST.

Comment: You could try storing results in some sort of dictionary. Try seeing if you could store the result of str(Fraction(y/x).limit_denimator() with a unique key and looking up that value first before computing it every time. Also try avoiding prints if you just need the final value.

Comment: Every problem of project Euler should be solvable by a computer run of at most 60 seconds. So I suggest you look for a faster method.

Comment: Thanks. My final code actually didn't have print within that loop. So what you're implying is that I should split this code into two processes, with one of those processes being cached. Isn't that 'for y in range(1,x):' the longest step, as it needs to loop around each time 1/3 - 3/3 , all the way to 1/100,000,000 - 100,000,000 - 100,000,000?

Comment: Your algorithm looks to be O(n^2). I'd look for a different algorithm with a lower order.

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm has bad complexity, as others have mentioned, but you are also using `Fraction` wrong. Use the two-argument version, and definitely don't convert and compare to strings. You are also constructing and calling `Fraction(y/x).limit_denominator()` *twice*, for no good reason.

This will speed up the code dramatically, but it won't help the algorithmic complexity:

```
order = 1000
x = 5
count = 0
while x <= order:
    for y in range(1, x):
        frac = Fraction(y, x)  # don't use y/x
        if frac.numerator != y:
            # print(frac)  # if you *must* print, reuse this
            count += 1
    # print(" ")
    x += 1

count = (count + 1) * 6 + (order - 1) * 6
print(count)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll probably need to rework this code over anyway, but you definitely made it a bit quicker.

Comment: I just ran the code again. What took 40 seconds to run before takes a second now! You made this code way faster, thanks again!